# hide/show a div with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide/show a div with AngularJS i have tried so many tutorials that doesn't work and i end up choosing the following the code from here [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHidehttp://)but it doesn't work either

can you help me to find the problem?

PS:I'm using angular 1.6.3

```
<html data-ng-app="crm">
<head>
  <title>Product Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ............
  <style type="text/css"> 
  .animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .animate-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
  .animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
  }
  .check-element {
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  it('should check ngHide', function() {
  var checkbox = element(by.model('checked'));
  var checkElem = element(by.css('.check-element'));
  expect(checkElem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
  checkbox.click();
  expect(checkElem.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="ProductController">

  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" style="position: absolute;top:0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;margin: auto;">

  <div class="panel panel-info spacer"><!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button> -->
  <div class="panel-heading"><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"/><b> Product Form</b></div>
  <div class="panel-body">

   <div class="check-element animate-show-hide" data-ng-hide="checked">
   <form class="form-horizontal" name="prodForm" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        .....
      </div>
        ....
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-sanitize.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not just use  `document.querySelector(".form-group").style.display = 'none';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is you dont create `module` and `controller` . Create new file and post this code in it

```
(function() {
  angular.module('crm',[])
         .controller('ProductController', ProductController)

  ProductController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function ProductController($scope) {

  }
})();
```

And dont forget inject to html

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Here is plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/sytU3IMgSpHreVlEDzOR?p=preview